# Kendo Grid DataSourceRequest ArgumentException trying to sort

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using this code to get my data and push it to the Kendo Grid

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(GetData(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private DataSourceResult GetData(DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var Items = _db.Item.Local.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => new
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Title = x.Title,
        LastEdited = x.User.LoginName,
        Category = x.CategoryItem.Title,
        DateEdited = x.DateEdited
    });
    return Items;
}
```

Using no model in the view for the Grid, letting the Grid figure everything out. This all works and I can browse through pages too. However the moment I add in a sorting method it throws me this exception for example:

```
Invalid property or field - 'Category' for type: Item
```

And each subsequent request fails because it has the sort in the DataSourceRequest until I reload the page to clear the request. Am I missing something here in terms of configuration that I need to add to this code?

Comment: yeah, because your Grid tell `DataSourceResult` that `"I'll sort by Category "`. But in your DataSource (_db.Item.Local) ,It doesn't have any field named `'Category'` . (your x => new{Category = x.CategoryItem.Title,} just select `Category ` after the 'Sorting' had been completed). So, you can try something like : _db.Item.Local.Select(x=> new {Category = x.CategoryItem.Title,}).ToDataSourceResult(request) .

Comment: Ahh ofcourse! That fixed it, if you repost it in an answer I'll mark it as one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yeah, because your Grid tell DataSourceResult that `"I'll sort by Category "`.

But in your `DataSource (_db.Item.Local)` ,It doesn't have any field named 'Category' .

(your x => new{Category = x.CategoryItem.Title,} just select Category after the 'Sorting' had been completed).

So, you can try something like :

```
_db.Item.Local.Select(x=> new {
    Category = x.CategoryItem.Title
    }).ToDataSourceResult(request)
```